# Input text via Javascript ECMAscript problem

Tags: javascript, input

I'm learning Javascript and I'm trying to input a text in a field, click on a button and change a paragraph innerHTML.

I've already done that successfully. But now I want to make a correction on the field, but when I click the button, nothing happens.

```js
//These are the variables
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var bt = document.getElementById("bt");
var para = document.querySelector("p#paragraph");

//event calls the insert().
bt.addEventListener("click", insert);

//The function changes the innerHTML
function insert() {
  para.innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
//The textfield to input the name
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name here"> <br> //The button
<input type="button" value="Click" id="bt"> //The Paragraph to be changed
<p id="paragraph">...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS is run when its script tag is loaded by the browser. Your problem is that, when the page loads, you're setting the value of `name` to the **current** value of the text field (which is empty when it loads). Move

```js
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

**into** the event listener and it should work.

---

Here is a tidied version:

```js
const name = document.querySelector('#name');
const bt = document.querySelector("#bt");
const para = document.querySelector('p#paragraph');

bt.addEventListener("click", function() {
  para.innerHTML = name.value;
});

// Alternatively, if you don't care for IE
// bt.addEventListener("click", () => para.innerHTML = name.value);
```

```html
<!-- The textfield to input the name -->
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name here">
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click" id="bt"> <!-- The button -->
<p id="paragraph">...</p> <!-- The Paragraph to be changed -->
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because your `name` variable is assigned once at initial script execution **before** the button is clicked and before the input is filled by the user.

To make it work, move `var name = document.getElementById("name").value;` inside 
`function insert()` so that `name` is assigned whenever the button is clicked.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/36570mf9/3/).